# Read all the contents in ini file into ordered dictionary with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

My configuration ini file:

```
[Component]
Componentnames1 = lf_object_road_mapping_Cfg,lf_preprocessing_Cfg
Componentnames2 = lf_database,lf_object
Componentnames3 = lf_object_road_mapping
Componentnames4 = fu_input_interface,fu_radar_configuration
Componentnames5 = Association,Association_Distance
```

This is the code for reading the above section ini file:

```
dictionary = {}
for section in config.sections():
    dictionary[section] = {}
    for option in config.options(section):
        dictionary[section][option] = config.get(section, option)
```

for the above piece of code, I am reading the dictionary with the keys and values in random sequence.

Actual output I could get after execution:

```
{'componentnames2': 'lf_database,lf_object',
 'componentnames4': 'fu_input_interface,fu_radar_configuration',
 'componentnames3': 'lf_object_road_mapping',
 'componentnames1': 'lf_object_road_mapping_Cfg,lf_preprocessing_Cfg',
 'componentnames5': 'Association,Association_Distance'}
```

Expected output:

```
{'componentnames1': 'lf_object_road_mapping_Cfg,lf_preprocessing_Cfg',
 'componentnames2': 'lf_database,lf_object', 
 'componentnames3': 'lf_object_road_mapping',
 'componentnames4': 'fu_input_interface,fu_radar_configuration',
 'componentnames5': 'Association,Association_Distance'}
```

Comment: you seem to be familiar with `collections.OrderedDictionary`, so have you tried using it?

Comment: yes, i had tried using it, but i could get the same answer.

Comment: Could you please show your attempt with `OrderedDict` that still failed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using OrderedDict?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = OrderedDict()

for section in config.sections():
    dictionary[section] = {}
    for option in config.options(section):
        dictionary[section][option] = config.get(section, option)
```